# HazelCast-Active session list

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, hazelcast

I am using Hazelcast in Spring. I want to know if there is a way through which i can print all the active session id in HazelCast.

Can someone provide me the information for the same ?

Regards.

Comment: What is "active session list"?

Comment: By "Active session" you mean, the list of active nodes?

Comment: @A.K.Desai  Active session means i want the session id of all the users who are logged in.

Answer (score 0):

If you have defined the below elements in your `web.xml` then you can get the active session list directly from the IMap.

```
  <!--
    Name of the distributed map storing
    your web session objects
  -->
  <init-param>
    <param-name>map-name</param-name>
    <param-value>my-sessions</param-value>
  </init-param>
```

The IMap `my-sessions` would be holding all the active sessions.